# Getting typerror on assigning to null?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, vue-router

Using Nativescript-vue (~2.0.0) and integrating vue-router (^3.0.6) via this [tutorial](https://www.vuejsradar.com/getting-started-with-building-mobile-apps-with-nativescript-and-vuejs/), I get an error:

> file:///app/bundle.js:876:7: JS ERROR TypeError: Attempted to assign
>   to readonly property. (CoreFoundation) *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: TypeError:
>   Attempted to assign to readonly property. at 1
>   @file:///app/bundle.js:876:7 2
>   ./router/index.js@file:///app/bundle.js:924:34 3
>   **webpack_require**@file:///app/bundle.js:76:34 4   @file:///app/bundle.js:630:84 5
>   ./app.js@file:///app/bundle.js:653:34 6
>   **webpack_require**@file:///app/bundle.js:76:34 7   checkDeferredModules@file:///app/bundle.js:45:42 8
>   @file:///app/bundle.js:149:38 9
>   anonymous@file:///app/bundle.js:150:12 10  evaluate@[native code] 11 
>   moduleEvaluation@[native code] 12  promiseReactionJob@[native code] 13
>   require@[native code] 14  anonymous@file:///app/starter.js:2:8 15 
>   evaluate@[native code] 16  moduleEvaluation@[native code] 17 
>   promiseReactionJob@[native code] ', reason: '(null)'

I have this code:
app.js:

```
import Vue from "nativescript-vue";
import router from '~/router';

new Vue({
    router
}).$start();
```

which uses this router/index.js:

```
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

import Startup from '../components/Startup'
import OfficeHome from '../components/Office/OfficeHome'

const routes = [
  { path: '/home', component: Startup },
  { path: '/officeHome', component: OfficeHome },
  {path: '*', redirect: '/home'}
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

router.replace('/home');
module.exports = router;
```

The pages are basically:

```
<template>
    <Page class="page">
        <ActionBar title="testing " class="action-bar" icon="" />

        <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column" justifyContent="center" class="full-height">
            <!--Add your page content here-->
            <StackLayout class="container">
                <FlexboxLayout alignItems="center">
                    <Label textWrap="true" text="test tech"
                           class="intro-text" />
                </FlexboxLayout>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Button class="btn btn-primary" @tap="$router.push('/home')">Home</Button>
                    <Button class="btn btn-primary" @tap="$router.push('/officeHome')">Office</Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </FlexboxLayout>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
</script>
```

Not sure if it makes a difference, but here is my package.json:

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "com.company.me",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.0.0"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "5.0.0"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "nativescript-dev-appconfig": "^1.0.2",
    "nativescript-nfc": "^3.0.1",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "nativescript-vue": "~2.0.0",
    "nativescript-vue-devtools": "^1.1.0",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.8",
    "tns-core-modules": "~5.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.6",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "~7.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "~8.0.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~0.17.0",
    "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "~2.0.0",
    "node-sass": "~4.9.0",
    "vue-devtools": "^5.0.0-beta.1",
    "vue-loader": "~15.4.0",
    "webpack-synchronizable-shell-plugin": "0.0.7",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "winston-color": "^1.0.0",
    "nativescript-vue-target": "^0.1.0",
    "nativescript-vue-externals": "^0.2.0"
  }
}
```

Being new to JS/NativeScript, I am not sure where this error is occuring.  I think the error indicates the router/index.js except there is no line 34.

Any idea what is being assigned where?

Comment: Currently, integration with Vue Router is unsupported. Until the team resolves the issue, please use manual routing. https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/routing/vue-router/

Comment: I thought that, but the example I found appears to use it without issue?  I was using manual routing, but coudln't find a way to navigate on a condition rather than button click:  if (true) "$goto('page1')" else "$goto('page2')" where I have this: Vue.prototype.$goto = function (to, options) {
    this.$navigateTo(this.$router[to], options)
}

Comment: By the time the article was written, Vue Router was partially supported but later the support was removed / discontinued. At the moment only manual routing is supported.

Comment: Thank you, I will resume my manual routing approach.